# Polynomial equation in C++

Tags: c++, class

How do I create a polynomial equation using class in C++

I have got this assignment that is due day after tomorrow. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Surely there's more to the assignment than "create a polynomial equation using class in C++". That's far too vague a specification for anyone to work on.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please checkout the [tour], [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Comment: First you need a type that represents a polynomial, then you need to define some representation of an equation. (But I suspect that you need to evaluate the polynomial rather than define an equation.)

Comment: There's got to be a library for this since this question has been asked a plethora of times.  Search the internet for "C++ StackOverflow polynomial class"

Comment: Good luck on getting your polynomial assignment working in two days.  I have posted a design for you to consider.

Comment: Asking HW questions is legitimate in SO, but with context and fair effort, we ain't here to do your job for you.
please post the question in its entirely, what have you tried, what issues did you run into? 
or ask ChatGPT, It'll probobly give you what you want :)

Answer (score 1):

You should learn or review algebra and the [definition of a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20polynomial%20is,x2%20%E2%88%92%204x%20%2B%207).

### Polynomial

A polynomial is made up (or contains) zero or more *terms*.

### Term

A term consists of:

- Multiplier (Coefficient)
- Variable (Base)
- Exponent

### Represent a Term

A term can be represented as a `class`:

```
class Term
{
  double m_multiplier;
  double m_variable;
  std::string m_variable_name;
  double m_exponent;
};
```

### Polynomial Representation

A polynomial is a container and commonly can be represented as a `vector` or `list`.  Many school requirements require the representation to be a list:

```
struct Polynomial_List
{
    std::list<Term> terms;
};
// Or
struct Polynomial_Vector
{
    std::vector<Term> terms;
};
```

If you need to write your own linked list, you can modify the `Term` class to be a node:

```
struct Poly_Node
{
    Term      m_data;
    Poly_Node *p_previous;
    Poly_Node *p_next;
};
```

### Building Upon The Foundation

You'll need to augment your classes with the following functionality:

- Formatted Input, e.g. `operator>>`
- Formatted Output, e.g. `operator<<`
- Addition
- Subtraction
- Evaluation
- Simplify (combine terms with equal bases and exponents).

In your extra time, you may want to implement *Multiplication* and *Division*, and maybe sorting of the polynomial, which will require functionality to compare `Term`s.

### Representation Simplification

If your polynomial has only one base (e.g. `x^2 + x + 6`) you can simplify the `Term` to contain only coefficients and exponents:

```
struct Term_Simplified
{
    double m_coefficient;
    int    m_exponent;
};
```

The exponent has changed to integer to make life easier.